# ssh keys in /etc/ssh keep being regenerated on startup

Tags: openssh

I have set up a Raspian Buster OS with /etc in its own partition. Whenever I reboot the machine, the ssh keys in /etc/ssh keep being regenerated. I have checked jounrnalctl log, but it doesn't show anything. Another strange aspect is when the keys are regenerated they always have an older date/time that always stays the same. I also tried removing the keys and regenerating them via `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`. On reboot, the date of the files revert to that previous date again along with new keys. How do I track down and solve this problem?

**Update:**
I had not mentioned that I was using an overlayFS earlier. In order to try the `mount --bind / /mnt/dsk` suggestion, I turned the overlayFS off. After doing so, the problem still remains, but now the new keys being generated have the current timestamp on the files. The /mnt/dsk/etc/ssh/ keys never change.

Comment: What's the timestamp on the newly generated keys? Are you running an NTP client? Are the keys regenerated before the system time is synchronized?

Comment: 1. How do you know the keys keep getting regenerated if they have the same date/time as the previous instance? 2. Is `/etc` being mounted early enough in the boot sequence? 3. If you `mkdir -p /mnt/dsk; mount --bind / /mnt/dsk`, is there a `/mnt/dsk/etc/ssh`? Does it contain the newly-generated keys?

Comment: @Kusalananda - The timestamp is always the same - an older date than current. Possibly, but new info below.

Comment: @roaima - Because their contents change each time. 2. Don't know. 3. No. I have some more info that I'll add with an edit to the original post.

Comment: If this problem still exists, please switch off Overlay FS (as you have mentioned in the update part of the question) and redescribe the problem. I can't identify which parts of "_the problem still remains_" you're referencing, and which parts are no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

After having hard time configuring SSH server on CentOS, because of constanty regenerating the new keys, I have found the file `/etc/sysconfig/sshd` with the following content

```
# Configuration file for the sshd service.

# The server keys are automatically generated if they are missing.
# To change the automatic creation uncomment and change the appropriate
# line. Accepted key types are: DSA RSA ECDSA ED25519.
# The default is "RSA ECDSA ED25519"

AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=""
# AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS="RSA ECDSA ED25519"

# Do not change this option unless you have hardware random
# generator and you REALLY know what you are doing

#SSH_USE_STRONG_RNG=0
SSH_USE_STRONG_RNG=1
```

after I commented out `AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=""` , the SSH server stoped regenerating keys on startup

On Debian however, I did not had to do anything because there the keys are not regenerated if they are missing or during startup.